# Error again. I encounter this error when I send my post, Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, mongodb, postman

[image: This is my code What I'm getting please]

[[image: This is what I am expecting]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fIZA.png

I don't know why I get this error, what should I do ?

Comment: The command `res.status(...).json(...)` appears on lines 30, 39 and 43 and all these are executed. Write `return res.status(...).json(...)` instead, because `res.json` does _not_ exit the function.

Comment: Please don't share images of code. Just copy your code into the post and format it in a code block.